# Laravel dependency installation on live server

Tags: laravel, composer-php, mailchimp, laravel-routing

I have uploaded a laravel site on live server and now I wanted to install a library like MailChimp. On local server I do it using composer but I want to do it on live server where the site is hosted and running . How to
install dependency and connect to hosting server using command line. Is it possible to access the hosting server file using DOS etc and run composer.

Comment: If you don't have SSH on the server, you can install it locally, then upload your `vendor` directory along with the rest of the Laravel install. All Composer does is generate that `vendor` directory for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply , let me try these suggestions .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can connect to the server through ssh and have access to the command line but it depends on the server, you might have the rights to install other programms or you may not...to get your hands on composer and install new dependencies you probably need to have those rights to install.
What type of server you have...VPS or Shared host. Probably on a VPS you can set up ssh connection...on a shared host things depend on what they have allowed you to have access to.

Comment: First let me try your suggestions. how I will connect to install dependencies. after that if you can suggest me whether there is another way to use that just install dependencies on local server and after that upload the changed files or folders only not all the project file again. I installed a dependency and tried to upload some file that I knew that are new but on local it was okay but on live serve there were a lot of missing and error were thrown.